# jquery :not + :contains selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having difficulty in selecting only elements that contain a certain value.

```
              if (autoCostBatches) {
                if ($('#noCostRecovery').attr('checked')) {
                    var tester= "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < autoCostBatches2.length; i++) {
                        tester = tester + autoCostBatches2[i].items + ", ";
                        }
                    var userString = tester.substring(0, tester.length - 2);
                    console.log(userString);
                    element = $('td:not(:contains(' + userString + '))');
                    if (element.length) {
                        elementParent = element.parent();
                            checkBox = elementParent.children('td').children('input');
                            checkBox.prop('checked', true);
                    }

                } 
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < autoCostBatches.d.batches.length; i++) {
                    element = $('td:not(:contains(' + autoCostBatches.d.batches[i].items + '))');
                    found = $.inArray(element, test) > -1;
                    if (element.children().length && found === false) {
                        elementParent = element.parent();
                        checkBox = elementParent.children('td').children('input');
                        checkBox.prop('checked', false);
                    }
                }
            }
```

here is the printed userstring to console and appears to be right.

[image]

and here are the elements in a table. Note that there is a td element containing 630316 and 632848 split by a comma. This to me looks correct but when I run the function all checkboxes are being checked which should not happen.

[image]

Comment: Post some of the HTML.

Comment: It's not the html cause I can select the two items no problem. The issue is when trying to select all items except those two.

Comment: Where is that printed `userstring` you showed us coming from? Where do you select the checkboxes and how does your html markup look like?

Comment: where are you checking/unchecking checkbox ?

Comment: It would be helpfull if you could set up a complete example

Comment: added but I dunno will it be much help. I can run this funtion no problem if selecting only those two but I can't do it if selecting all td but those two.